# Jquery to expand div next to selected element

Tags: jquery, html

My Html looks like

```
<h3><a href="#" title="story title">Story Title</a>
    <img class="expandstory" src="/images/plus.png" /></h3>
<div class="description">Short description about the story</div>
```

I need jquery which will expand description when user clicks on expandstory image.

I used `

```
$(".expandstory").click(function()  {
     $(".description").slideUp(500);
     $(this).nextAll('.description:first').slideToggle(500);
}`
```

but no use. Please provide me a solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".expandstory").click(function()  {
     $(".divisionWrap div ul").slideUp(500);
     $(this).parent().nextAll('.description:first').slideToggle(500);
});
```

Also, as an suggestion you don't need to use nextAll() looking at the logic.

You can just do:

```
$(this).parent().next('.description').slideToggle(500);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. $(this).parent() will return h3 tag. Am I right.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(".expandstory").click(function()  {
     var el = $(this).closest('h3').next('.description');
     $(".description").not(el).slideUp(500);
     el.slideToggle(500);
}
```